# Startled by a notation of operator for combining two signals

Tags: signal

I am studying electronics and when practising, I got stuck at this simple problem of summing two signals. I believe I know how to work out everything except the combination of the two signals with two "minus signs".

The problem is 
[image]

i.e. one signal of 0.1 V (rms) going through amplifier block with gain of -3.3 dB and other signal of 0.4 V (rms) going through amplifier block of voltage gain of 0.902 are combined together and then go through amplifier block of gain 4 dB. Both signals consist from an uncorrelated noise.

I think that the attenuated signal from the first source is 
$$ V_1 = 0.1 \cdot 10^{\frac{-3.3}{20}} \approx 0.068$$
and that the signal from the second source is $$V_2 = 0.4\cdot0.902 \approx 0.36$$

I have then tried to add these signals together and get the \$V_\text{out}\$:
$$
V_\text{out} = (V_1+V_2) \cdot 10^\frac{4}{20} \approx 0.680
$$
which is quite far from the correct answer of \$582\:mV\$.

I believe that I have not combined the signals correctly — I have also tried combining them with negative signs, but that would just yield negative voltage. Could someone please explain me what this notation of combining signal means?

Comment: For uncorrelated sources. use rms summation, not linear summation.

Comment: Thanks :) I knew I was missing something simple. Thus just for clarity, when summing uncorrelated signals A,B, the output is \$\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V1 is 100mV attenuated by 3.3 dB and +3.3 dB = a ratio of 1.462.

Therefore V1 becomes 100mV/1.462 = 68.4 mV (as you have said).

V2 is 400mV reduced by 0.902 to 360.8 mV (as you have said)

Here's where the problem lies - these are uncorrelated noise sources and have to be added using pythagoras....

So, the output from the summer is \$\sqrt{0.0684^2 +0.3608^2}\$ = 367.2 mV

This is then increased by 4 dB (ratio of 1.584) to 1.584 x 367.2 mV = 582 mV.

Comment: Just for clarity, while the noise signals are mathematically combined 'using Pythagoras' or 'using RSS', it is probably better for long term understand of the principles to say that uncorrelated signals are combined by **adding power**, whereas correlated signals are combined by **adding voltage**

Comment: @user44635 You put it very nicely!

Comment: @user44635 Thanks for the explanation behind the formula. And what if the signal was correlated only to a certain level? - e.g. simple example of two noise signal with correlation coefficient of 0.5?

Comment: @Pter Good question, I like where you're going. Rather than answer you directly, I'll give you a hint. Think about what the correlation coefficient means. Given two signals, what formula is used to calculate it? Or, how would you construct a signal partially correlated to another, by weighting components that were fully corelated, and uncorrelated?

Comment: @user44635 If I read you correctly, the expected signal voltage would be just weighted sum of rooted sum of squares and of sum of the input? If I had two signals, \$A\$ and \$B := A^2\$, the expected output signal voltage would be \$ \rho (A+B)+(1-\rho)\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\$?

Comment: @Pter The point is that correlation coefficient is defined by how the signals add, not the other way round, so using terms like self power and cross power in an equation of definition. I don't bother to understand what correlation coefficient is when it's not 1 or 0, because it's not as fundamental as how the signals behave. If people want to use the term correlation coefficient, good luck to them, I only dig out the actual equation when I need to for my day job, and that's not now.